# wxpython unittest with modal dialog

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython GUI, and I am attempting to use unittest to test some of my modal dialogs.  I tried to follow the example given here (you have to scroll down to the bottom of the page): http://wiki.wxpython.org/Unit%20Testing%20with%20wxPython, but it does not work for me.  It simply freezes in the middle.

I've adapted the code from the wiki to this:

```
btn_id = wx.NewId()

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Test')
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, btn_id, label="OK!!")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.close_dialog)

    def close_dialog(self, event):
        print 'close me'

class TestMyDialog(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = wx.App()
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None)
        self.frame.Show()

    def tearDown(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.app.Exit)
        self.app.MainLoop()

    def testDialog(self):
        def clickOK():
            clickEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, btn_id)
            self.dlg.ProcessEvent(clickEvent)
            print 'finished clickOK'

        wx.CallAfter(clickOK)
        self.ShowDialog()

    def ShowDialog(self):
        self.dlg = MyDialog(self.frame)
        self.dlg.ShowModal()
        self.dlg.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

To my understanding, what should happen is that ShowDialog is called, then gets 'stuck' on ShowModal, at which time clickOk should run (called by wx.CallAfter).  This seems to happen, but for some reason the click event isn't actually processed, and the tests hangs.  When I run MyDialog not in testing the event binding works fine and the dialog closes when the Ok button is clicked.

I shouldn't need app.mainloop() to be able to ProcessEvent, right?  What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the unittests in Phoenix https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix , look at test_dialog.py and the base staff in wtc.py